# French full dates

Tags: c#, localization

I'm using

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd dd MMMM yyyy",new CultureInfo(user.CultureCodeISO2)
```

For dates in dutch.
Now my requirements changed and I need to support full dates in french and english aswell.

**It seems to me like there is no generic solution that results in a correct date in all 3 languages ... especially the following tricky parts marked in bold**

**le** 15 décembre 2012 | December 15, 2012

le 29 mars 2011 | March 29, 2011

**le 1er** avril 2011  | April 1, 2011

Do I really need to write a custom function that adds the le and changes the order of the format depending on the culture?

ToLongDateString() doesn't work for me, this results in e.g. "mercredi 31 décembre 2003"
without the **le**

Comment: Why are the results incorrect?

Comment: Why do you think the date isn't correct without the "le"?

Comment: Because my translator told me it had to be like that, it's for use in a PDF letter for print.. I just follow the orders

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your user object is and what it delivers in CultureCodeISO2. I suppose it is an int for the culture identifier.

As you see in the link below there is no pattern for an article.
If you do want this article then you maybe need to declare your own format:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

If I were you I would write an extension method calling the ToString method internally and adding the article depending on selected language.

```
    public static string ToStringWithArticle(this DateTime dateTime, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        var dateTimeString = dateTime.ToString(format, provider);
        if (provider == new CultureInfo("fr-BE") || provider == new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
        {
            dateTimeString = "le " + dateTimeString;
        }
        return dateTimeString;
    }
```

You guess what I mean?

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to avoid here, because every time a new culture pops up on the requirements list i'll have to fix up this thing. But I'll guess i'll have to use a variant of this because there seems to be no built in solution I can trust...

Comment: I know, it is no good feeling solution. But with extension methods it is dealable in a good way, because you only have one central point you have to change something.